# Adding iCloud support to an application that uses Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

At the moment I'm working at the first version of a simple application that uses `Core Data` with `SQLite` to store its data. My client doesn't want to perform any backup/synch operation for this first version but I'm pretty sure that they'll ask me to implement `iCloud` support in a second version.

My question is: Can I work without thinking about iCloud since the next App version and then just add support for it when (if) my client requires it? 
My doubt is that adding support for iCloud in a second moment would be a pain in the neck but on the other side I'm not sure that this feature will be ever necessary.

Note: This application support only iOS7 >

Comment: If you use a UIManagedDocument it should be pretty straightforward to provide iCloud sync later.  Having said that there are a number of sync considerations that you may or may not have to deal with, such as seed data, duplicate data, handling merge errors, dealing with coordinator notifications and so on.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald I read that UIManagedDocument has some serious bugs and it is not reliable so I prefer to avoid it. Am I in error?